# Scaling an image to best fit the viewport

Tags: javascript, image, math

Suppose I have a viewport of an arbitrary size (eg, a browser window). I want to scale an image of arbitrary aspect ratio and resolution to fit inside of this viewport in a way that maximizes the resolution.

I'm having difficulty getting the code to work for circumstances where the image is both too tall and too wide. What equation can I use to figure out if I should scale this arbitrary image by width or by height?

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
var aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
if(tooWide && tooTall)
{
    // Figure out if it's better to scale on height or width by 
    if((imageWidth - viewporthWidth) > (imageHeight - viewporthHeight))
    {
        adaptedWidth = (1.0 - padding) * viewporthWidth;
        adaptedHeight = adaptedWidth / aspectRatio;
    }
    else
    {
        adaptedHeight = (1.0 - padding) * viewporthHeight;
        adaptedWidth = adaptedHeight * aspectRatio;
    }
}
else if(tooWide)
{
    adaptedWidth = (1.0 - padding) * viewporthWidth;
    adaptedHeight = adaptedWidth / aspectRatio;
}
else if(tooTall)
{
    adaptedHeight = (1.0 - padding) * viewporthHeight;
    adaptedWidth = adaptedHeight * aspectRatio;
}
else
{
    adaptedWidth = imageWidth;
    adaptedHeight = imageHeight;
}
```

I'm having some circumstance where images of a certain size are not being scaled at all. For example, a 3000 x 1997 image is being resized to 1342 x 893 when my viewport size is 1492 x 855. The aspect ratio is correct, but the height is wrong. This implies the condition of the nested if statement is wrong (and indeed, it evaluates to 1003 > 1104, which hints that we should be scaling by height.

I assume that this means that the equations used for scaling the image are insufficient.

Side note: this code is JavaScript that is being used to scale an image (using the browser's native scaling via the `width` and `height` attributes on the image element). In the code above, `padding` is a percentage to that creates a minimum amount of padding around the image (so it doesn't take up the entire viewport). I included this in the code because the default padding is 0.10, and that affects the numbers that I mentioned.

Comment: Why use JS when CSS can handle this for you? Isn't `img{height:auto;width:100%}` what you need?

Comment: @elclanrs That would only handle the "too wide" situation, not the too tall.

Comment: Then use `background-size:cover` for example. I'm pretty sure you can do what you want without JS. Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @elclanrs, here's a demo of the very rough code I've written so far. It's essentially a "hover over link to image to view the image" script: http://jsbin.com/gejomuna/1/edit

Comment: As for why `background-size:cover` won't work, the main issue is that I still have to resize this overlaying "hovering div" to have the correct size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be comparing the ratios of image to viewport, not the absolute differences.

Something along these lines:

```
if((imageWidth / viewporthWidth) > (imageHeight / viewporthHeight))
```

This will essentially compare the percentage difference instead of absolute difference.  This is important because when you scale the image, the image is reduced by a percentage, not by an absolute amount in both width and height.

**EDIT**:

You can see here, this is an example with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Yq6/1

And with the updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Yq6/

In this example, the absolute difference in width is larger, but the percentage difference in height is higher.  The old code scaled based on width (incorrectly) and the new code scales on height.

Comment: Hmm, now the aspect ratios are all funky (after changing just that line).

Comment: I don't see how that `if` could affect your aspect ratio.  It's not part of the calculation.

Comment: is it possible that the contents of the conditionals is off? They seemed correct prior to the conditional change (except for the occasional image that would not be scaled).

Comment: @Mike Example added, seems fine to me.

Comment: @Mike the code in your jsbin is different than in the question.  The part screwing up your aspect ratio is that youv'e changed whether you multiply or divide by `aspectRatio`.  They were right in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up by using git reset, which removed some change I made in the time since I made the question. Your answer works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My final answer:

```
var aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
var viewportRatio = viewportWidth / viewportHeight;
var adaptedHeight = imageHeight;
var adaptedWidth  = imageWidth;


if (viewportRatio > aspectRatio) // scale by width or height?
{   adaptedHeight *= viewportWidth / imageWidth;
    adaptedWidth  *= viewportWidth / imageWidth;
}
else
{   adaptedHeight *= viewportHeight / imageHeight;
    adaptedWidth  *= viewportHeight / imageHeight;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post a brand new answer when you need to make a small change.  You can simply edit your existing answer.  I would suggest deleting one of these answers.